# Help required regarding using inline R commands in overleaf

Tags: overleaf, r, inline

I am using overleaf to compile my R codes into a pdf file. For a chunk of code, we use for example:

```
<<>>=
mean(reading)
max(reading)
min(reading)
@
```

But now I want to use these commands inline. I want my output to be like:

"The mean of the data is `mean(reading)`, the maximum is `max(reading)`, and the minimum is `min(reading)`", where the `mean(reading)` etc will directly print the output of the command inline. But I don't quite know how to do that.

Please help, and I apologize if this seems trivial, for I am quite new to R.

***THANK YOU***

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But the chunk I mentioned in the question works in overleaf if we just add the extension .RTex instead of .Tex in the file in overleaf.

Comment: sorry my first comment was wrong https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Knitr

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly now!

Comment: if you have working code can you self answer, to get this off the unanswerd list

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Done. Please check for any corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the document in the link posted by David Carlisle in the comments, using `$\Sexpr{command}$` works.

For example, if we need the mean of the data inline, we can say, "The mean of the data is `$\Sexpr{mean(reading)}$`" and same for other commands.

Thanks a lot for helping out.

Comment: The output of a function as `mean()` alone could be a bad idea for inline texts  (supposedly to be read for humans). Some rounding, according to the size of mean, is more than advisable to avoid a ridiculous precision  (e.g.:  `\Sexpr{round(mean(x),2)} €`  to type `9,45 €` instead of  `9,45226283 €`).